# MSSQL Linux - RETAIL ASSERT: Expression=(NT_SUCCESS(status)) File=drtl.cpp Line=5326

Tags: sql-server, linux, database, sql-server-2017

I have problem with MSSQL Server installed on linux, core logs growing up quickly and i see some crash logs, db works fine - i can make queries but sometimes application cannot open connection. How to fix that? Its related with my distro? I use "Linux Mint 18.3"

crash.json:

```
  {
        "reason": "0x00000004",
        "processName": "sqlservr",
        "pid": "17895",
        "instanceId": "2ae9114e-8eca-453e-a5c2-bbeb6251cd6c",
        "crashId": "24fbd029-e331-4707-9aaf-f847858c98b3",
        "threadState": "0x00007f0e2d2916e8",
        "threadId": "17899",
        "libosThreadId": "0x4",
        "buildStamp": "61b979cc9f8723080867e1f890ff5650b3b0dae804f3da8ece065f41216bd0bb",
        "message": "RETAIL ASSERT: Expression=(NT_SUCCESS(status)) File=drtl.cpp Line=5326",
        "stackTrace": [
            "file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000033D157",
            "file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000033C8AB",
            "file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000206DBA",
            "file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000033C19F",
            "file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000033844A",
            "file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000037D4E1"
        ],
        "last_errno": "2",
        "last_errno_text": "Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu",
        "distribution": "Linux Mint 18.3",
        "processors": "4",
        "total_memory": "16723791872",
        "timestamp": "Thu Apr  9 09:50:38 2020"


   }
```

also i don't see any suggestions in error.log

Comment: error.log:
https://pastebin.com/w2ZUfPfd

Comment: SQL Server is not supported (officially) on Linux Mint, so that could easily be your first problem. As for the error *"Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu"*, according to Google that means "There is no such file or directory", and I doubt your Linux Mint *does* have a Windows System 32 folder... I suggest using a supported operating system. If you don't want to install the full OS, don't forget SQL Server is supported in Docker, or you could use different Container Software (for example LXD) to run a Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 Container.

Comment: @Larnu +1 this, in fact I don't know why anyone would want to run MS SQL Server on Linux _without_ using Docker - otherwise there's simply too many variables and cases where things could go wrong.

Comment: Personally, I don't use Docker when installing it on Linux, @Dai . I actually do use LXD and find it works very well. But I was used to LXD already, so it was just easier than learning Docker too. ;)

Comment: @Larnu, Dai thanks guys! I will use a solution with docker image.